# Orthogonality and Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Here: http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/203/MatrixOnVectors/leastSquares.htm

"Notice that $\mathbf{b} - \text{proj}_W\mathbf{b}$ is in the orthogonal complement of $W$ hence in the null space of $A^T$"

Why does it mean it is in the null space? I don't follow.

Comment: Note that $W$ is the column space of $A$.  Thus being orthogonal to $W$ is equivalent to being in the null space of $A^T$ since the row space of $A^T$ is simply the transposed image of $W$, to make the matrix multiplication $A^T (\mathbf{b} - \text{proj}_W \mathbf{b}) = 0$ work out.

Comment: That said, you really need to include such pertinent details in your Question statement.

Answer (score 1):

We have the linear system $Ax=b$, where the columns of $A$ are the vectors $v_1, v_2,\ldots v_n$.
$W=span(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$.  Since $b^*=b-proj_W(b)$ is orthogonal on  $W$, it belongs to the orthogonal complement of $W$.
But the  orthogonal complement of $W$ consists in all vectors $u$ that are orthogonal to $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$: $W^\perp=\{u\:|\: <v_1,u>=0, <v_2, u>=0, \ldots, <v_n,u>0\}=\{u\:|\: v_1^Tu=0,
v_2^Tu=0, \ldots, v_n^Tu=0\}$. These conditions, i.e. $v_k^Tu=0$, $k=\overline{1,n}$, are equivalent  to $A^Tu=0$, and thus we can conclude that $W^\perp=Null(A^T)$. That is why $b-proj_W(b)$ belongs to $Null(A^T)$.

Answer (score 0):

By Projection theorem, we have  $b = b_1 + b_2$ where $b_1(= proj_W(b)) \in R(A), b_2 \in ~\mbox{orthogonal complement of} ~ R(A) = N(A^T)$. Thus $b_2 = b-proj_W(b) \in N(A^T)$

Comment: What is the notation $R$ and $N$?

Comment: $R$ stands for  range space of $A$ and $N$ stands for null space of $A$.